# How to increase the size of Gridview RepositoryEditText ? winforms devexpress

Tags: winforms, gridview, devexpress

I used Repository EditText in Gridview to write description of some items. When i click enter button on keyboard, the new rows will comes to type but the height of the RepositoryEditText will not increase. If user Click enter button keyboard i need to extend the EditText height. I want to display both lines in same cell of gridview. How to complete my task ? Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TextEdit editor doesn't support the multi-line feature. So, you need to use MemoEdit as you already did. To display several lines, increase the GridView.RowHeight property, for example, to 60. On the other hand, in order to adjust a row height to completely display a cell content, enable the GridView.OptionsView.RowAutoHeight option.

Comment: I got one more error if I set GridView.OptionsView.RowAutoHeight = true my display member of RepositoryLookup Edit didn't show. Anyone help me to overcome this.